# "503/Failed to write to server" on a photo upload

Tags: facebook, file-upload, photo

When uploading a photo with the Facebook REST API, I occasionally get a "503/Failed to write to server"  from Facebook.

I see in a capture of the TCP traffic that while I am sending the image with SSL, the Facebook server will suddenly send an Encrypted Alert (code21) and shortly after send a bunch of RST flags. This always happens in the middle of the transfer.

I have tested with various different images and it seems like the bigger the image, the more likely it is to fail. For example, a 3kb image will have a 100% success rate. A 400kb image will have ~50% success rate. A 600kb will have ~25 success rate and a 800kb or bigger image seems to fail all the time.

I should also add that there are times when even a much larger image (2000kb) will upload successfully many times in a row but once one failure happens, the results I mentioned above start to happen.

So my question is, what can be causing this behavior? Why would the upload fail on one attempt and succeed on subsequent attempts with the same image?